# Can I update a non-sql server database from within a sql server stored procedure?

Tags: database

Is it possible to update a different ODBC database from withing a SQL Server Stored Procedure.  For example, say I have Access, MySQL, etc.  I update my SQL Server database and I want the stored procedure to update the other ODBC database.  Kind of like a poor man's replication.

Is there a better way to replicate between different database systems?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a Linked Server should solve your problem. You have a choice of providers, including ODBC.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  Also, can't you use .net languages in SP's now?  Can they use ODBC?

Comment: You can. I've been using it successfully with the software I write in my day job. If you're interested, check out the SQLCLR: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136.aspx